# Web Config Transformed Multiple Times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, web-config-transform

I am using `MSBuild` command line to build and I used Configuration as `Release` but all configurations are applied. I am unable to find that what the issue could be.

I have three configurations
under `Web.config`

- `Web.Debug.config`
- `Web.Live.config`
- `Web.Release.config`

I am using following command of `MSBuild`

```
"%MSBuildTools14.0_x64_Path%\MSBuild" %system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\Application\Application.csproj /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=bin
```

Any Help would be appreciable !!

**Edit :** I have a node in `web.config` as

```
<connectionStrings configSource="Config\Sql.config" />
```

which I am overriding in `Web.Release.config` and `Web.Live.Config` as

```
<connectionStrings configSource="Config\Sql.Release.config" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(configSource)" />

<connectionStrings configSource="Config\Sql.live.config" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(configSource)" />
```

and I am getting `Config\Sql.live.config` in final `Web.Config`

So I think I am using `configuration` `Release` but all configurations are been used for transformation.

Please Help!

Comment: can you post how the transformed web.config looks like? when you say all configurations are applied, do you mean you see duplicates?

Comment: @Ahsan I have some more content which can be helpful